# SQL - Combine different rows into a single row with different ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table from different id needs to combine into a single row

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
        | Id  | Col1| Col2| Col3|
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
        | 1   |     |   1 |     |
        | 2   |     |   2 |     |
        | 3   |   3 |     |     |
        | 4   |   4 |     |     |
        | 5   |     |     |   5 |
        | 6   |     |     |   6 |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

What I want to achieve in the same table.

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
        | Id  | Col1| Col2| Col3|
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
        | 1   |   3 |   1 |   5 |
        | 2   |   4 |   2 |   6 |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

What I had tried to aggregate the rows from using different id

```
Select ID
      ,ID1 = max(Col1)
      ,ID2 = max(Col2)
      ,ID3 = max(Col3)
 From  Tbl
 Group By ID
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, you say "source table" but only show one table format...Is there a second table you're using that you didn't show?

Comment: Hey Marcus Parsons, I had tried this 

Select ID
      ,ID1 = max(Col1)
      ,ID2 = max(Col2)
 From  YourTable
 Group By ID

Comment: Please edit your question, as well, with what you've tried and any additional table structure, so that anyone else answering can also get a clearer picture.

Comment: Please explain the necessary logic required to obtain the required result from the sample data. I only see `Id` `1` & `2` in the expected result. What happen to `3` to `6` ?

Comment: Hey Squirrel, ID 3 to 6 will not appear because the values are combined into ID 1 and 2

Comment: and the logic to `"combine"` is ?

Comment: sorry what I meant "combine" is to aggregate the values of Id 3 to 6 into Id 1 and 2.

Comment: And how do you perform the `aggregate` ? what is the logic ?

Comment: I would like to reference this post as an example of my logic on aggregate. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210150/merge-multiple-rows-into-fewest-number-of-rows-of-distinct-values

Comment: Since you have a reference, you should be able to implement the same as the answer in that reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data

```
create table test(
   Id   INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Col1 INTEGER  
  ,Col2 INTEGER
  ,Col3 INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO test
(Id,Col1,Col2,Col3)
VALUES
(1,NULL,1,NULL),
(2,NULL,2,NULL),
(3,3,NULL,NULL),
(4,4,NULL,NULL),
(5,NULL,NULL,5),
(6,NULL,NULL,6);
```

`UNION` the result of `Max` function with `Min` function

```
SELECT 1         AS ID,
       Min(col1) Col1,
       Min(col2) Col2,
       Min(col3) Col3
FROM   test
UNION
SELECT 2         AS ID,
       Max(col1) Col1,
       Max(col2) Col2,
       Max(col3) Col3
FROM   test
```

In addition you can use `multiple join` and `Subbquery` and `Where` condition to

```
SELECT a.id1 AS id,
       b.col1,
       a.col2,
       c.col3
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
                OVER (
                  ORDER BY id ) id1,
              *
       FROM   Test
       WHERE  col2 IS NOT NULL) a
      JOIN (SELECT Row_number()
                     OVER (
                       ORDER BY id ) id1,
                   *
            FROM   Test
            WHERE  col1 IS NOT NULL) b
        ON a.id1 = b.id1
      JOIN(SELECT Row_number()
                    OVER (
                      ORDER BY id ) id1,
                  *
           FROM   Test
           WHERE  col3 IS NOT NULL) c
        ON a.id1 = c.id1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=200ceeeb7be7d3e3507d22548c3ae2e2)